# "spot yours" meaning in the context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> ...Yes, I am sure you are surprised to hear this - no doubt you will say that Potter has always been Dumbledore's favorite - but I feel bound to tell you that Dumbledore may not be in charge at Hogwarts much longer and the people who count have a very different - and probably more accurate - view of Potter's behavior. I shall say no more here, but if you look at the Daily Prophet tomorrow you will get a good idea of the way the wind is blowing - and see if you can **spot yours** truly!
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of  the Phoenix</sub>

What does "spot yours" mean? Especially, what 'yours' refers to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrase is "spot yours truly".

"Yours truly" is a (pretentious) way to refer to yourself. So the speaker is saying "see if you can spot me (in the newspaper tomorrow)".

Comment: This self-referential “yours truly” resembles one traditional way to close a letter.  In that context, those words appear just before the signature — yours truly, Gary Botnovcan.

Comment: I usually see "truly yours".